# pfsense - redirect custom URL to specific server/port

Tags: pfsense

I have pfsense router and local web server connected to it. That web server has wiki page available under specific port number (under default port there is another web service availabe), so I would like to make it easy accessible.
Is there any way to configure redirection on pfsense like:

```
wiki.domain --> webserver:12345/wiki/index.php
```

?

Comment: No, that's a webserver's (HTTP Redirect) job.

Comment: What's the web server listening on port `80`? Can you configure it?

Comment: Wiki is now on 8777 - I can configure it. Another service is on 80 - I can't modify it.

Comment: The question remains. What is on port `80` and why can't you do any changes?

Answer (score 2):

In pfsense I dont think you can.

Please use another free firewal appliance, like sophos utm, as it can do it with WAF host redirection. Check the virtual web server setting.

https://community.sophos.com/kb/en-us/120388

See that image, you see different port for the same source IP

[image]

Its one of the cool feature of sophos utm

An example there; https://community.sophos.com/products/unified-threat-management/f/web-server-security/50188/waf-host-header-redirection

Answer (score 2):

IP firewalls cannot do this as they are not aware of the content of the HTTP request, specifically the Host: header in this case.  You would need to modify the configuration of the port 80 service to handle a name-based virtual host and to proxy traffic for wiki.domain to the alternate port (via a ProxyPass directive).